# Determinar si existe una ruta con la clase File

Tags: java

He empezado a trabajar con la clase `File` de Java.

Se me pide hacer un ejercicio que recoja una ruta y determine si existe o no en mi sistema de archivos y, en caso de que exista, decir si es absoluta o relativa.

He cacharreado un poco por la API de Java buscando los métodos más oportunos. Aún así, el programita no acaba de hacer lo que quiero.

Éste es mi codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;


public class ArchivoDirectorio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        String cadena = new String();

        System.out.println("Introduce una ruta");
        cadena=teclado.next();

        //Convierto la ruta a un "objeto File" para poder utilizarla en los metodos
        File ruta = new File(cadena);


        if(ruta.exists()){
            if(ruta.isAbsolute()){
                System.out.println("La ruta existe y es absoluta");

            }else{
                System.out.println("La ruta existe y es relativa");
                System.out.println("Su ruta absoluta es "+ruta.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("La ruta no existe");
        }

    }
}
```

El programa no acaba de funcionar con todas las rutas que le paso. Supongo que el `File.exists()` no busca en todo el disco.

Algunos resultados en funcion de lo introducido:

- Si le paso `\users`: Me dice que existe y que es relativa (bien).
- Si le paso cualquier ruta absoluta me dice que existe y que es absoluta (bien).
- Si le paso `\addins` (carpeta dentro de `C:\windows`) me dice que no existe.

Supongo que el problema está relacionado con en qué partes busca coincidencias el `File.exist()`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que busque coincidencias en todo mi sistema de archivos?

Comment: Es confuso el tema de las "unidades" de Windows (que no existen en Unix). En realidad `\addins` buscaría en el raíz de la unidad en curso, imagino que `C:`, por lo que la respuesta es correcta. Windows es muy ambiguo con la definición de ruta absoluta y relativa cuando se trata de las unidades. Las trata como absolutas únicamente si incluyen la unidad al comienzo, pero debes recordar que en UNIX toda ruta que comienza por el separador de rutas es una ruta absoluta, pero en Windows no porque falta la unidad, considerándose **una ruta absoluta... relativa a la unidad en curso**.

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar lo que te dije en la respuesta? ¿Tienes alguna duda? Deja un comentario si es así e intentaré resolver la duda que te haya quedado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a la confusión que genera el tema de las [rutas absolutas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_absoluta) y [relativas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_relativa) en el sistema operativo Windows:

> Las rutas absolutas señalan la ubicación de un archivo o directorio **desde el directorio raíz del sistema de archivos**.

En UNIX el directorio raíz es único, pero en Windows cada letra de unidad tiene su propio directorio raíz.

En realidad, cuando accedías a `\users`, estaba buscando en la ruta absoluta (desde el raíz) de la unidad en curso (imagino que `C:`), por lo que la respuesta es correcta y el directorio `C:\users` existe.

Como he dicho, Windows es muy ambiguo con la definición de ruta absoluta y relativa cuando se trata de las unidades. En el caso de Java, parece que las trata como absolutas únicamente si incluyen la unidad al comienzo, pero debes recordar que en UNIX toda ruta que comienza por el separador de rutas es una ruta absoluta, pero en Windows no es así porque **falta la letra de la unidad**.

Por lo que podríamos considerar que la última ruta, `\addins`, **es una ruta absoluta, relativa a la unidad en curso**. Estaría comprobando la existencia de `C:\addins` si la unidad en curso es `C:`, independientemente de si estás en `C:\Windows` o cualquier otro directorio, por lo que esa ruta no existe y el resultado que te muestra es correcto.

Si quieres que sea una ruta relativa real, introduce `addins` sin el separador de directorios al comienzo.